# Bug in our web display?

Tags: bug

I notice a possible bug in our display.

In this question [How do I convert my PhD dissertation so that it can be published as a book?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/6086/546)

Javeer Baker's comment appears on top of Suresh's comment.

In general, if A writes a comments, then B writes a comment 5 hours later, A's comment would appear on top of B's.

In the case of the subject question, something is wrong because Javeer wrote the comment 5 hours **after** Suresh did his.

Something is wrong.

Comment: Perhaps there was an earlier comment that Javeer Baker was replying to, but that subsequently got removed.

Comment: @gerrit is right - check the edit history of the question to see what was actually changed - it doesn't relate to Suresh's later comment.

Comment: Okay, I was confused. Maybe it's fine. The last thing I want to see is a bug. Thanks. To the mod, if it's not a problem, please close this question. Thanks, my bad.

Comment: @scaaahu: It definitely doesn't look like a bug, but I agree that the fact that comments can disappear might lead to confusing thread. I'll remove the corresponding comment in the question. As for this question, closing would be wrong (because it doesn't really fit any of the closing category), just write an answer (or perhaps gerrit/EnergyNumbers can do it, there is no reputation impact anyway) and accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I was confused by Javeer Baker'comment replying to someone else's comment which was removed later(thus become invisible to me).

Thanks to gerrit and EnergyNumbers who pointed it out.

I apologize for this false alarm.